# Angular JS have pages from 2 different states visible during state transition ( for animation purpose )

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to create a transition animation when loading different pages, e.g 
when user leaves one page, then the other pages transitions in by animating "position: relative; left: n px" starting from off-screen position and moving into view. When the new view finishes the transition and covers the old view, then the old view can be discarded.

The animation itself is easy.  Problem is that Angular destroys the old view immediately so i cant run any animations on it.

How could i make such transition work ?

Comment: Have you looked at [this documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate).  It seems that angular puts transitions on both enter and leave, so it should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last example on this page is close what you're describing: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView, I don't think Angular destroys the old view immediately but only after the transition. During the view transition, the "view-animate-container" attaches the class "ng-leave ng-leave-active" to the old/current view "view-animate". The new view "view-animate" is added with class "ng-enter ng-enter-active".

AngularJS documentation currently has

```
.view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left:-100%;
}
```

which hides it. So in order to see the old view during the transition, you just need to modify the css of "ng-leave.ng-leave-active" to something like this

```
.view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left:0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```